# Jupyter Notebook: ImportError: cannot import name 'default'

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When trying to start Jupyter with the command Jupyter Notebook, I am getting this below error:

```
File "/anaconda/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 4, in <module>
import notebook.notebookapp
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", 
line 63, in <module>
from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py", line 16, in <module>
from nbformat import sign, validate, ValidationError
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 24, 
in <module>
from traitlets import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'default'
```

Any idea what is missing?

Answer (score 1):

I use: 

`pip3 install --user --upgrade traitlets`

Works fine for me.

Comment: I've tried it and outputs same error. Also I've uninstalled and re-installed and still output same error. Any other solutions you came up with?

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled traitlets package and reinstalled it. The problem went away. Not sure how it broke in the first place.